# How to unpack and append in one line (Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to unpack arguments and append a value in one line? I'm trying to do something similar to the below:

```
a = [*ProductA.get_names()] + ["hello"]
```

but I keep getting the error:

```
type object 'ProductA' has no attribute 'hello'
```

Is there a way to do this in one line? I have tried appending "hello" as well.

Comment: Can we see your code? How do we know what `ProductA`, `get_names()` are

Comment: "Is it possible...?" Yes. The code you show does not cause the error you say it does. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are looking for could be

```py
a = [*ProductA.get_names(), "hello"]
```

but the error message you are sharing seems to say your `get_names` method encounters a bug.